# Using Airbnb API with Facebook Login

Tags: python, facebook, authentication, python-requests

This is my first time dealing with logging in using Facebook credentials. I want to be able to query listings in Airbnb through my account. My original account in Airbnb is through Facebook login. Here is the sample request on airbnb page:  http://airbnbapi.org/#login-by-facebook.

I am not sure where can I get my client_id and Facebook's access token. Although it does point to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens to get the user access token but, if I understand it correctly, it requires me to create an app. I am not sure what flow of authentication is required for me to use Airbnb API.

I have already looked at Airbnb docs to search for client_id but, of no use.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
import json

API_URL = "https://api.airbnb.com"
LISTING_ENDPOINT= "https://api.airbnb.com/v2/search_results"

post_query = {
    "client_id": "I HAVE NO IDEA WHERE TO GET IT",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "currency":"USD",
    "assertion_type":"https://graph.facebook.com/me"
    "assertion":"HOW SHOULD I GET THIS ONE?",
    "prevent_account_creation":True
}

# I think this should be able to log me in and I should be able to query listings
_ = requests.post(API_URL, post_query).json()

query = {
    "client_id":"FROM ABOVE",
    "user_lat": "40.00",
    "user_long":"-54.31"
}


listings = requests.get(LISTING_ENDPOINT, json=query).json()
```

Comment: There does not seem to be a public api but accessing the private one seems trivial

Comment: How can I get my client id?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem as you. I figure it out finally. The tool i used is the advanced function of requests library, that is Session(),  for saving cookies. The important part for login with a third party account is to find the link we need to post the cookies. The following is my code.

```
import requests
x=requests.Session() #savig the cookies when you click the "log in with facebook button"
y=requests.Session() #saving the cookies for parsing the airbnb listing.
account={'email':'your_facebook_account','pass':'your_facebook_ps'}
log_in_with_facebook_click=x.post("https://www.airbnb.jp/oauth_connect?from=facebook_login&service=facebook") 

#all the cookies up to now is saved in "x"
my_first_time_cookies=x.cookies.get_dict()
real_login_link=log_in_with_facebook_click.url

real_log_in=y.post(real_login_link,account,cookies=my_first_time_cookies)
#the real login link is saved in "log_in_with_facebook"
#pass the cookies and your facebook account information to the real login link
#you should have logged into airbnb.For testing the log in, we do the following. We check the reservation data.

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page=1
test=y.get("https://www.airbnb.jp/my_reservations?page="+str(page))
#Remember that the cookies we use to access airbnb website after loggin in is saved in "y"
test_html=BeautifulSoup(test.text,'lxml')
print(test_html.text)
#you should have looked your tenants reservation information.
```